# Parse JSON response from Eventbrite API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing, eventbrite

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from the Eventbrite API in Ruby but am having trouble. Specifically, JSON is not handling nested hashes which then appear as an array containing a single string. Here's my script:

```
  require 'eventbrite' 
  require 'csv'
  require 'uri'
  require 'json' 
  require 'rest-client'

  response = RestClient.get 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?organizer.id=4705752287&token=mytoken''

 response = JSON.parse(response)
`enter code here`puts response #this returns a ruby hash
```

When I print out this hash, here's what I get (below). What I need are the "name" (text format) and "description" (text format) within the "event" key, which are currently inaccessible in a single string inside an array. Please advise! I am new to APIs and Parsing JSON. Thank you!

Here's what I get back:

```
{"pagination"=>{"object_count"=>1, "page_number"=>1, "page_size"=>50, "page_count"=>1}, "events"=>[{"name"=>{"text"=>"Feb Fest Workshops @ the MIT Museum for Middle School Students", "html"=>"Feb Fest Workshops @ the MIT Museum for Middle School Students"}, "description"=>{"text"=>"  \nMiddle school students are invited to spend one day or the entire week at the MIT Museum and explore such topics as holography, physics & photobraphy, robotics, DNA, and structural engineering. Our educational team will help you think about developments that MIT researchers are making in these subjects. Each day will include two 2-hour Museum workshops, a gallery tour, and an on-campus field trip.  \nThis opportunity is limited to 20 middle school (6th - 8th grade) students per day. Participants should bring a bag lunch that does not require refrigeration and their signed liability form.  Individual students only; no groups please. Students may be brought to the Museum no earlier than 9:30 a.m. and must be picked up by 3:45 p.m.  \nEvery year, during the Massachusetts school vacation week in February, the MIT Museum celebrates National Engineers Week with engineering-specific activitiites, workshop, and demonstrations led by MIT students.  \n  \n  \n  ", "html"=>"<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\"><BR></SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\">Middle school students are invited to spend one day or the entire week at the MIT Museum and explore such topics as holography, physics &amp; photobraphy, robotics, DNA, and structural engineering. Our educational team will help you think about developments that MIT researchers are making in these subjects. Each day will include two 2-hour <A HREF=\"http://web.mit.edu/museum/education/workshops.html\" REL=\"nofollow\">Museum workshops</A>, a gallery tour, and an on-campus field trip. </SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\"><STRONG>This opportunity is limited to 20 middle school (6th - 8th grade) students per day. Participants should bring a bag lunch that does not require refrigeration and their <A HREF=\"http://web.mit.edu/museum/education/pdfs/FEBFest%20Waiver%202016.pdf\" REL=\"nofollow\">signed liability form.</A>  Individual students only; no groups please. Students may be brought to the Museum no earlier than 9:30 a.m. and must be picked up by 3:45 p.m.</STRONG><BR></SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\">Every year, during the Massachusetts school vacation week in February, the MIT Museum celebrates National Engineers Week with engineering-specific activitiites, workshop, and demonstrations led by MIT students. </SPAN></P>\r\n<P> </P>\r\n<P> </P>\r\n<P> </P>"}, "id"=>"20514138340", "url"=>"http://www.eventbrite.com/e/feb-fest-workshops-the-mit-museum-for-middle-school-students-tickets-20514138340?aff=ebapi", "start"=>{"timezone"=>"America/New_York", "local"=>"2016-02-16T09:30:00", "utc"=>"2016-02-16T14:30:00Z"}, "end"=>{"timezone"=>"America/New_York", "local"=>"2016-02-19T15:30:00", "utc"=>"2016-02-19T20:30:00Z"}, "created"=>"2016-01-06T15:30:44Z", "changed"=>"2016-01-17T19:00:20Z", "capacity"=>80, "status"=>"live", "currency"=>"USD", "listed"=>true, "shareable"=>true, "online_event"=>false, "tx_time_limit"=>900, "hide_start_date"=>false, "locale"=>"en_US", "is_locked"=>false, "privacy_setting"=>"unlocked", "logo_id"=>"17744153", "organizer_id"=>"4705752287", "venue_id"=>"5023762", "category_id"=>"115", "subcategory_id"=>"15001", "format_id"=>nil, "resource_uri"=>"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/20514138340/", "logo"=>{"id"=>"17744153", "url"=>"https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fimg.evbuc.com%2Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.evbuc.com%252Fimages%252F17744153%252F84178497408%252F1%252Foriginal.jpg%3Frect%3D0%252C12%252C274%252C137%26s%3Dc0e0d68a95d928599ac5c33d1e115a76?h=200&w=450&s=9fc9f7a1f911240daa25bf3b6ad7c77f", "aspect_ratio"=>"2", "edge_color"=>"#ffffff", "edge_color_set"=>true}}]}
```

Comment: Can you post raw JSON as received from the API instead of forcing us to register for `eventbrite` developer API?

Comment: Just remove the options, as you're asking it to be symbolized. `response = JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: @WandMaker I posted raw JSON above. I think the previous code also had what you need. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @sidegeeks adding the option (and removing it) didn't have any impact on the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you've posted, so far, so good! I think what you're looking for are the queries to access the values (name-text and description-text).

In my experience, (parsed JSON) API responses are close to always composed of a number of (nested) hashes and (nested) arrays. You can navigate these hashes by providing the key-values and you can navigate the arrays by providing index-values. You can also iterate over any (sub)hashes/(sub)arrays.

So, given:

```
response = {"pagination"=>{"object_count"=>1, "page_number"=>1, "page_size"=>50, "page_count"=>1}, "events"=>[{"name"=>{"text"=>"Feb Fest Workshops @ the MIT Museum for Middle School Students", "html"=>"Feb Fest Workshops @ the MIT Museum for Middle School Students"}, "description"=>{"text"=>"  \nMiddle school students are invited to spend one day or the entire week at the MIT Museum and explore such topics as holography, physics & photobraphy, robotics, DNA, and structural engineering. Our educational team will help you think about developments that MIT researchers are making in these subjects. Each day will include two 2-hour Museum workshops, a gallery tour, and an on-campus field trip.  \nThis opportunity is limited to 20 middle school (6th - 8th grade) students per day. Participants should bring a bag lunch that does not require refrigeration and their signed liability form.  Individual students only; no groups please. Students may be brought to the Museum no earlier than 9:30 a.m. and must be picked up by 3:45 p.m.  \nEvery year, during the Massachusetts school vacation week in February, the MIT Museum celebrates National Engineers Week with engineering-specific activitiites, workshop, and demonstrations led by MIT students.  \n  \n  \n  ", "html"=>"<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\"><BR></SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\">Middle school students are invited to spend one day or the entire week at the MIT Museum and explore such topics as holography, physics &amp; photobraphy, robotics, DNA, and structural engineering. Our educational team will help you think about developments that MIT researchers are making in these subjects. Each day will include two 2-hour <A HREF=\"http://web.mit.edu/museum/education/workshops.html\" REL=\"nofollow\">Museum workshops</A>, a gallery tour, and an on-campus field trip. </SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\"><STRONG>This opportunity is limited to 20 middle school (6th - 8th grade) students per day. Participants should bring a bag lunch that does not require refrigeration and their <A HREF=\"http://web.mit.edu/museum/education/pdfs/FEBFest%20Waiver%202016.pdf\" REL=\"nofollow\">signed liability form.</A>  Individual students only; no groups please. Students may be brought to the Museum no earlier than 9:30 a.m. and must be picked up by 3:45 p.m.</STRONG><BR></SPAN></P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #333333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.479999542236328px;\">Every year, during the Massachusetts school vacation week in February, the MIT Museum celebrates National Engineers Week with engineering-specific activitiites, workshop, and demonstrations led by MIT students. </SPAN></P>\r\n<P> </P>\r\n<P> </P>\r\n<P> </P>"}, "id"=>"20514138340", "url"=>"http://www.eventbrite.com/e/feb-fest-workshops-the-mit-museum-for-middle-school-students-tickets-20514138340?aff=ebapi", "start"=>{"timezone"=>"America/New_York", "local"=>"2016-02-16T09:30:00", "utc"=>"2016-02-16T14:30:00Z"}, "end"=>{"timezone"=>"America/New_York", "local"=>"2016-02-19T15:30:00", "utc"=>"2016-02-19T20:30:00Z"}, "created"=>"2016-01-06T15:30:44Z", "changed"=>"2016-01-17T19:00:20Z", "capacity"=>80, "status"=>"live", "currency"=>"USD", "listed"=>true, "shareable"=>true, "online_event"=>false, "tx_time_limit"=>900, "hide_start_date"=>false, "locale"=>"en_US", "is_locked"=>false, "privacy_setting"=>"unlocked", "logo_id"=>"17744153", "organizer_id"=>"4705752287", "venue_id"=>"5023762", "category_id"=>"115", "subcategory_id"=>"15001", "format_id"=>nil, "resource_uri"=>"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/20514138340/", "logo"=>{"id"=>"17744153", "url"=>"https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fimg.evbuc.com%2Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.evbuc.com%252Fimages%252F17744153%252F84178497408%252F1%252Foriginal.jpg%3Frect%3D0%252C12%252C274%252C137%26s%3Dc0e0d68a95d928599ac5c33d1e115a76?h=200&w=450&s=9fc9f7a1f911240daa25bf3b6ad7c77f", "aspect_ratio"=>"2", "edge_color"=>"#ffffff", "edge_color_set"=>true}}]}
```

To return the values you wish, you can use a query like so:

**name text:**

`response["events"][0]["name"]["text"]`
or
`response["events"].first["name"]["text"]`

**description text:**

`response["events"].first["description"]["text"]`

I figured out what the levels of nesting were and so how to query them by using the gem [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print), which transforms any *single-line* hash/array/json into a correctly *nested* one.

To use: do `gem install awesome_print` in terminal, then require it in your file/irb/console with `require 'awesome_print'` and call `ap` instead of `print` or `puts`, like so: `ap response`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much @Glenn, that does it! Appreciate your detailed response and the awesome_print gem.